# Substring and sorting a sql table

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I have a table which look as follows

```
ID       Date            Reason       Tag
1        2 Jun 2015      Create New   9_0_17
2        2 Jun 2015      Name Change  Non User Event
3        2 Jun 2015      Modified     9_0_17
4        2 Jun 2015      Saved        9_1_17
5        2 Jun 2015      Create New   9_0_18
```

I would like a select statement where I can filter the table by where the tag starts with 9 and the value after the last underscore in the tag column is 17.  The results will looks as follows

```
ID       Date            Reason       Tag
1        2 Jun 2015      Create New   9_0_17
3        2 Jun 2015      Modified     9_0_17
4        2 Jun 2015      Saved        9_1_17
```

Just a note that value after first underscore can go up to 999 and the value after the second underscore can go up to 99999.

Comment: Sql Server, Oracle, MySql?

Comment: What have you tried till now and are you facing any issues with your query?

Comment: where Tag like '9%_17' ?

Comment: Is the format always n_n_nn (or 'Non User Event')?

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: The format can be both n_nnn_nnnnn or text.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need this:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Reason, Tag
FROM *your_table* 
WHERE TAG LIKE '9_%_17'
```

Comment: it should be LIKE '9%_17'

Comment: Yes that would work but what would happen if the tag value is 9_17_18. The select statement will still select wont it? I only want rows when the value after second underscore is 17.

Comment: I just tried and the above statement will also select 9_177_188 and so on :/.

Comment: Are you sure? I have a similar field in a table of my application that works exactly as your TAG field. And my query on that fields works with that query

Comment: All i changed was 'Where tag like '9_%_1'.  The query selects rows which have 1 after the second underscore and also 11 and so on.  e.g. 9_0_1, 9_0_11 etc.